# How can I check every time I have opened a specific program in my Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have been asked to pass a report that shows all the hours that I have opened a specific program in my Windows 10 since it was installed until today.
Is there any way to get a list or something similar with this information?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the program shortcut with:

Batch program:

Open notepad.exe

Write:

@echo off

C:\Program files\your program path

for /f " delims==" %%i in (c:\windows\temp\counter.txt) do set /A temp_counter= %%i+1
echo %temp_counter% > c:\windows\temp\counter.txt

Save it as counter.bat

Replace program shortcut with path to counter.bat

To see clicks:

Open notepad.exe c:\windows\temp\counter.txt

Comment: I have tried what you tell me but it didn't do me anything. Could you please show me a visual example or something?